# Google Cloud App Engine Task Purge Queue using Node.js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'm working on a project that uses GCP/GAE. I have a queue of tasks that is executed. In some cases I need to purge the queue contents. I have searched for API docs on how to do this, but have only found legacy outdated docs and they're only for python. I need a code example of how to purge a task queue by name using Node.js. I also did not find anything on Stackoverflow. I already have an instance of `CloudTasksClient()` that is used to `listTasks()` and it works just fine.

Is there a method for the client that will `purgeQueue(<queueName>)`? Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I noticed that purgeQueue is actually possible using Node client library. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to purge a queue using Node.js

```
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const client = new CloudTasksClient();

async function main () {
  const project = "PROJECT-ID";
  const region = "REGION"
  const queue = "QUEUE"

  const formattedName = client.queuePath(project, region, queue);

  client.purgeQueue({name: formattedName})
  .then(responses => {
    const response = responses[0];
    console.log(`Purged ${queue}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
main();
```

The proper syntax of the method should be `purgeQueue(request)` or `purgeQueue(request,callback)` where request is an object with a String property of "name".

Though the example is based from the older version, I was able to run this on client library version `2.1.0`.

Additional Reference: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/1.6.1/v2beta2.CloudTasksClient.html#purgeQueue